# Auto Select option form Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

i want to make my edit is auto select option but when i try is doesnt work. i need my form edit is auto select the data if i click data with id_cms_companies "1" from my table location is auto select and show in the first select option.
and its show the name of table cms_companies
here my code :

```
<select class='form-control' name='id_cms_companies'>
                        <option>- Companies -</option>
                        <?php 
                        $category = DB::table("cms_companies")->get();
                        foreach($category as $cat) 
                        {
                         if($cat->name == $row->id_cms_companies)
                         {
                          echo "<option value='$cat->name' selected>$cat->name</option>";
                         }
                         else
                         {
                          echo "<option value='$cat->name'>$cat->name</option>";
                         }
                        }
                         ?>
                        </select>
```

and here my controller :

```
public function getEdit($id)  {
        $data['row'] = locations::find($id);
        return view('locations_form',$data);
    }

    public function postEditSave($id) {
        $simpan= array();
        $simpan['name']=Request::input('name');
        $simpan['id_cms_companies']=Request::input('id_cms_companies');

        DB::table('locations')->where('id', $id)->update($simpan);
        Session::flash('edit', 'Data berhasil di Edit');
        return Redirect::to('locations');
    }
```

here my table :

[table locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBs7U.png)

and here for my

[table cms_companies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Gsi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should compare two IDs, no ID with Name

```
if($cat->name == $row->id_cms_companies) //wrong
if($cat->id == $row->id_cms_companies) //correct
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [laravel html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html), it will do it automatically

So you could do something like this:

```
$category = DB::table("cms_companies")->get()->pluck('name', 'id');
echo Form::select('id_cms_companies', $category, $row->id_cms_companies, ['class' => 'form-control']);
```

Read more about it here [docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#drop-down-lists)